# Firebase lazy loading

Tags: lazy-loading, firebase

Can I make firebase load my data lazily?  Let's say my app consists of a tree with a million nodes that the user can collapse, expand and modify.  The vast majority of those nodes will stay collapsed the vast majority of the time so it doesn't make sense to keep everything in memory.  As far as I can tell, firebase transfers everything in the database to the client on launch and is not meant to be used in any other way.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's incorrect. Firebase synchronizes data only as you request it. To accomplish something like this, it's all about how you store the data.

For instance, a simplistic example would be this structure, which achieves the desired result:

```
/records/root/record1
/records/root/record2
/records/record1/record1-1
/records/record2/record2-1
```

Now you do `ref.child('root_level').on('child_added'...)` for your starting point. When a node is expanded, run a `child_added` on the child path.

You could also use priorities, storing all the records in the same path and loading only those you need based on the priority:

```
/records/record1 (priority null)
/records/record2 (priority null)
/records/record1-1 (priority 'record1')
/records/record2-1 (priority 'record2')
```

Now, to retrieve your root records, you use:

```
ref.child('records').startAt(null).endAt(null)
```

When a node is expanded, you use the following:

```
ref.child('records').startAt(parentId).endAt(parentId)
```